# Gradle projects with independent configurations - proper way to declare dependencies

Tags: gradle

Using Gradle 6.9, we have a project where we want to release configurations independently from the rest of the project. All configurations are stored in a module, and we publish a zip with the configurations for later deployment in production. This part is working fine.

Our issue is making sure that the modules that depend on this configuration build. Declaring a dependency on the module is not working, since it doesn't build a jar file. We tried to declare a dependency like this:

```
    compile fileTree("${rootProject.projectDir}/path/to/module/resource/directory")
```

But this doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you can check on gradle official [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html) that you have two ways to do that .

```
configurations {
    antContrib
    externalLibs
    deploymentTools
}

dependencies {
    antContrib files('ant/antcontrib.jar')
    externalLibs files('libs/commons-lang.jar', 'libs/log4j.jar')
    deploymentTools(fileTree('tools') { include '*.exe' })
}
```

As you can see in the code example, every dependency has to define its exact location in the file system. The most prominent methods for creating a file reference are Project.files(java.lang.Object…​), ProjectLayout.files(java.lang.Object…​) and Project.fileTree(java.lang.Object) Alternatively, you can also define the source directory of one or many file dependencies in the form of a [flat directory repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver)

This would look like this

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib1', 'lib2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for transitive dependencies...